# Meaning of LSTM Size

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

This question might be very basic. But I'm having difficulty in understanding the `lstm size` concept. In RNN, we specify `lstm size`.
What is this `lstm size` means? Is it number of lstm cells? Or unrolled version of lstm which has length upto the size specified (e.g. 128)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would typically refer to the number of LSTM cells.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So `lstm size` is similar to number of neurons on basic NN? So if `lstm size` is 128 & `num_steps` is 30, then each lstm will unrolled till 30 units? Also, why you wrote "typically"? Is there any other importance of `lstm size`?

Comment: I mean it could be defined differently in different places, but the places I've seen it used have defined it as number of cells. So lstm size would be similar to number of neurons, and then num_steps would presumably refer to the amount of unrolling.

Answer (score 0):

So the LSTM can be considered as a map function:
$R^d$ by $R^d$ by $R^d$ ---> $R^d$ by $R^d$

(c,h) = LSTM(x,pc,ph)
pc and ph can be thought as two "hidden variales".
and the lstm_size mean the dimension d.